# Launching an event just before the app is closed

Tags: web-services, flash, shutdown

So, here it is my problem, I'm running a Flash app who is hosted in an html page that connects to a web service when it starts, what I need, is a way to launch/detect an event that communicates to that web service to say: "hey, I'm not here anymore" when the user:

- close the tab
- close the browser
- refresh the page
- anything not inside a flash controlled environment

How can I do that?, I mean, I'd need to find a way to send data to the web service even if the app is being shut down.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add some javascript: `window.onunload = function(){/*do stuff*/}`